# How can I make one part of view scrollable?

Tags: ios, xcode, html, uiscrollview, scroll

This has probably been asked a bunch, so I'm more looking for direction to somewhere I can research this, unless it is an easy straight-forward answer. I can't think of the propper terminology to search for it; I just keep getting the same standard `UIScrollView` info.

I understand how to make a scrollable view, but I can't find anything on making say a 310 x 310 pixel part in the center of my view to be scrollable, like a scrollable div in the center of a webpage so it can have a nice image border around the content that would scroll in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `addSubview` method of `UIView`.

Create a `UIImageView` that spans the size of the screen (or whatever space you would like it to take up).  This will contain the 'image border' you refer to.  Let's say that view is named `backgroundImageView`.

Then create your `UIScrollView`; let's say it's called `myScrollView`.  Now for this line:

```
[backgroundImageView addSubview:myScrollView];
```

That will add `myScrollView` inside `backgroundImageView` in the view hierarchy.  Now you set `myScrollView`'s position in the coordinate system of `backgroundImageView`.  So to center it, do this:

```
 [myScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake((backgroundImageView.frame.size.width - myScrollView.frame.size.width) / 2, (backgroundImageView.frame.size.height - myScrollView.frame.size.height) / 2, myScrollView.frame.size.width, myScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

And voila, you're done :)

Comment: cheers, then i guess i have to populate myScrollView with another view? i'm trying to read the apple documentation but i like to watch a tutorial aswell, i'm learning all this from scratch so the visual bit makes it easier for me.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  A `UIScrollView` is a container for other views; everything you want to scroll should be placed inside it with `addSubview` :)  And yeah, I can understand the visuals helping!  Hope your iPhone development journey goes well :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a UIScrollView and set its frame to the size and location that you want and then add it to another view.